API call from NextJS app throws a 403 if call is from client component, but not from server component
Like the title says, when I make a request to an external API from my client side component, I get a 403, but if I make it from a server component, it works just fine.
The reason I need to make the call from client side is because the user makes a selection and the request made depends on the selection, so useState() is used to manage the selection. The user selects a sector, and then the call to get industries by sector id is made.
The relevant client component code:
const { data: session } = useSession();
  const [sector, setSector] = useState<Sector | null>(null);
  const [industries, setIndustries] = useState<Industry[]>([]);
  const [industry, setIndustry] = useState<Industry | null>(null);

  const handleSectorSelection = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, value: Sector | null) => {
    setSector(value);
  };
  const handleIndustrySelection = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, value: Industry | null) => {
    setIndustry(value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const getIndustries = async (sectorId: number) => {
      const response = await getIndustriesBySectorId(sectorId, session?.jwt);
      setIndustries(response.result as Industry[]);
    };
    if (sector && sector.id != null) {
      getIndustries(sector.id);
    } else {
      setIndustries([]);
    }
  }, [sector, session?.jwt]);
return (...
     <SectorSelectDropdown
            options={sectors}
            onChange={handleSectorSelection}
            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Search" variant="outlined" />}
          />
          {industries && industries.length > 0 ? (
            <IndustrySelectDropdown
              options={industries}
              onChange={handleIndustrySelection}
              renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Search" variant="outlined" />}
            />
          ) : null} ...)

The sectors property is passed down from the parent component
The API call:
export async function getIndustriesBySectorId(sectorId: number, jwt?: string) {
  let result = null,
    error = null;
  if (!jwt) {
    throw new Error("Session JWT token not found.");
  }

  try {
    console.log(jwt);
    result = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_POSITIONS_SERVICE_URL!}/industries/sector/${sectorId}`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Cookie: `Authentication=${jwt}`,
      },
      credentials: "include",
    });
    if (!result.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Failed to fetch industry: ${result.statusText}`);
    }

    const data: Industry[] = await result.json();

    return { result: data, error: null };
  } catch (e) {
    error = e;
    return { result: {}, error: error };
  }
}

If I make the call from a server component, I would change things up within this file and get the session data directly (instead of passing them in) like this:
export async function getPositions() {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
  let result = null,
    error = null;

  if (!session?.jwt) {
    throw new Error("Session JWT token not found.");
  }...

So, is there a way to accomplish what I need to do with the current setup? Or is there a way to make my current client side component a server side component? I am new to NextJS, so perhaps my entire setup is wrong?

I'd suggest that you make a server action for the api call. That way you just have to update the useEffect to call the server action instead of the direct fetch.
Do not pass any auth or session data from the client to the server action directly, instead get fresh session auth/data on each request (server action call). And do not forget to validate the input before running the client input on the server, using a middleware is a very good solution in most cases.
